# MVC Radiobutton default value did not set after knockout data-bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, radio-button

I am using MVC strongly typed view to generate two radio buttons

```
<div>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Eligible)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Eligible,"true", new { id="yes", data_bind =       "checked: completeVM.Eligible " })
        @Html.Label("yes", "YES")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Eligible, "false", new {id="no", data_bind = "checked: completeVM.Eligible " })
        @Html.Label("no", "No")
</div>
```

If I don't use data_bind, when the page loads, the 'No' radio button will be set by default. But after I  add data_bind, neither radio button is checked. I noticed  in my view model, the Eligible was displayed as :"Eligible": false; if I check 'No' button, it will display as "Eligible":"false". How can I fix this so that when the page loads, the 'No' button will be checked by default. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. Radio button values are always a string. Yet you want boolean behavior. The easiest fix is to use an extra computed observable to do the translation for you:

Assuming 'this' points to your  viewmodel:

```
this.EligibleRadioHelper = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this.Eligible().toString();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this.Eligible(value === 'true');
    },
    owner: this
});
```

Bind against this new helper:

```
data-bind="checked: completeVM.EligibleRadioHelper"
```

When you want the boolean value (for logic or for persisting) use your original observable.

Answer (score 2):

You also can try using the `checkedValue` binding available in knockout 3 without the need to write a computed function for your view model.
Your code will become something like this:

```
<div>
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Eligible)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Eligible,"true", new { id="yes", data_bind =       "checked: completeVM.Eligible, checkedValue: true" })
    @Html.Label("yes", "YES")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Eligible, "false", new {id="no", data_bind = "checked: completeVM.Eligible, checkedValue: false " })
    @Html.Label("no", "No")
```